# Unable to open terminal in VSCode on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VSCode on my laptop (64 bit) to write and run C++ programs. The tutorial I am following tells me I need to type code in the Developer Command Prompt for the cl command to work in the terminal. However, whenever I try to open the terminal from the Terminal menu or by pressing `Ctrl+~`, I get the following error:

> "The window has crashed. We are sorry for the inconvenience. You can
> reopen the window to continue where you left off".

I tried reinstalling VSCode to no avail. I tried searching online but didn't find a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue, <!-- Launch with code --disable-extensions to check. --> Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: - Remote - WSL extension is needed

Does WSL work in general? Opening a WSL window from the remote menu (status bar lower left)? What's the full content of the WSL log?